# Angular DI via "Inline Array Annotation" giving a warning in WebStorm

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, webstorm

When using **Inline Array Annotation** to inject some dependency on a controller, WebStorm will give me the following warning.

> require() call is missing

Is it considered good style to require the script anyway, although it is globally available after injecting it, or can I recklessly suppress this warning? Is there a plugin or setting which takes care of such situations, noticing injected dependencies?

**EDIT:**

I made a mistake in the original post. I do inject the dependency into a controller, but I use the injection in another method afterwards. It's a plain JavaScript function. I might just have to convert that into a controller. Pretty new to angular. Sorry for that.

Comment: I don´t get this message in WebStorm. I guess your project settings are somehow wrong. So he interprets your code as e.g. node code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally I use explicit injection like below :

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

 angular
 .module('mod')
 .controller('Controller', CtrlFunction);


  CtrlFunction.$inject = ['depencencies'];

  function CtrlFunction(dependencies) { 

  }

})();
```

Please look for angular style guide by John Papa [angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)